# Shopify Cannot complete OAuth process. Could not find an OAuth cookie for shop url

Tags: node.js, shopify-api

I am trying to Complete OAuth process for Shopify and getting above mentioned error.

What it does?
A log in page appears, after my credentials it redirects to my URL which I also registered in  App URLs in Shopify Partners.

I am following documentation from Official Shopify Api https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-api-node

```
const session = yield shopify_api_1.default.Auth.validateAuthCallback(request, response, query);
```

this is where the problem is, if I get session, I can move on

looking forward for answers.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this problem. Have you found a resolution?

Comment: I used Local host instead ngrOK.
In you app setup in Partners.shopify, set app URL with local host, also call back URL with localhost